# removing quotes and double quotes from a list of words

Tags: python, string, debugging, replace, quotes

this is my first question on this site. Please forgive me for any formatting or language errors. So this question is based on a book called "think python" by Allen Downey. The activity is to write a python program that reads a book in text format and removes all the whitespace such as spaces and tabs and punctuations and other symbols. I tried many different ways to remove the punctuations and it never removes the quotes and double-quotes. They persistently stay. I'll copy-paste the last code I tried.

```py
import string

def del_punctuation(item):
    '''
        This function deletes punctuation from a word.
    '''
    punctuation = string.punctuation
    for c in item:
        if c in punctuation:
            item = item.replace(c, '')
    return item

def break_into_words(filename):
    '''
        This function reads file, breaks it into 
        a list of used words in lower case.
    '''
    book = open(filename)
    words_list = []
    for line in book:
        for item in line.split():
            item = del_punctuation(item)
            item=item.lower()
            #print(item)
            words_list.append(item)
    return words_list

print(break_into_words('input.txt'))
```

I have not included the code to remove the whitespace as they work perfectly. I have only included code for removing punctuations. All the punctuational characters are removed except for the quotes and the double-quotes. Please help me by finding the bug in the code or is it something to do with my IDE or compiler?
Thanks in advance

input.txt:

```
“Why, my dear, you must know, Mrs. Long says that Netherfield is
taken by a young man of large fortune from the north of England;
that he came down on Monday in a chaise and four to see the
place, and was so much delighted with it that he agreed with Mr.
Morris immediately; that he is to take possession before
Michaelmas, and some of his servants are to be in the house by
the end of next week.”

“What is his name?”

“Bingley.”

“Is he married or single?”

“Oh! single, my dear, to be sure! A single man of large fortune;
four or five thousand a year. What a fine thing for our girls!”

“How so? how can it affect them?”

“My dear Mr. Bennet,” replied his wife, “how can you be so
tiresome! You must know that I am thinking of his marrying one of
them.”

“Is that his design in settling here?”
```

The output I get is copied below:

> ['“why', 'my', 'dear', 'you', 'must', 'know', 'mrs', 'long', 'says', 'that', 'netherfield', 'is', 'taken', 'by', 'a', 'young', 'man', 'of', 'large', 'fortune', 'from', 'the', 'north', 'of', 'england', 'that', 'he', 'came', 'down', 'on', 'monday', 'in', 'a', 'chaise', 'and', 'four', 'to', 'see', 'the', 'place', 'and', 'was', 'so', 'much', 'delighted', 'with', 'it', 'that', 'he', 'agreed', 'with', 'mr', 'morris', 'immediately', 'that', 'he', 'is', 'to', 'take', 'possession', 'before', 'michaelmas', 'and', 'some', 'of', 'his', 'servants', 'are', 'to', 'be', 'in', 'the', 'house', 'by', 'the', 'end', 'of', 'next', 'week”', '“what', 'is', 'his', 'name”', '“bingley”', '“is', 'he', 'married', 'or', 'single”', '“oh', 'single', 'my', 'dear', 'to', 'be', 'sure', 'a', 'single', 'man', 'of', 'large', 'fortune', 'four', 'or', 'five', 'thousand', 'a', 'year', 'what', 'a', 'fine', 'thing', 'for', 'our', 'girls”', '“how', 'so', 'how', 'can', 'it', 'affect', 'them”', '“my', 'dear', 'mr', 'bennet”', 'replied', 'his', 'wife', '“how', 'can', 'you', 'be', 'so', 'tiresome', 'you', 'must', 'know', 'that', 'i', 'am', 'thinking', 'of', 'his', 'marrying', 'one', 'of', 'them”', '“is', 'that', 'his', 'design', 'in', 'settling', 'here”']

It has removed all the punctuations except for the double quotes and single quotes (there are single quotes in the input I guess).
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! While your example is already quite minimal, which is good, it is still missing an example input and both an expected and actual output.
Otherwise it's hard to help you exactly, as we have to guess what exactly is meant to happen. For more information, read the page about [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does the input text you're using have "smart quotes" in it? Those angled quotes aren't in `string.punctuation`. Those are the angled quotes that word processors tend to insert.

Comment: If you "debug" your code and "inspect" it - your IDE will always display " or ' ad start/end of the string - to make clear it is a string. Are those that you talk about? `print() ` your items and see if you see them in your cosole output

Comment: Also, please use `with open(...) as` instead of just `open`.

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your suggestions and advice. I have made a lot of improvements and changes to my question. Please help me.

Comment: Also make sure your minimal example is *complete*.  It needs `import string` and to call the function in the code block.  I'll edit as an example.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the comment and suggestion. I'm really sorry that I forgot to copy the import string part. I have added it now.

Comment: Ahh! Your output is a _list_, so it's printed in Python syntax. That's what's adding the quotes. If you don't want those quotes, don't print the list itself; instead, print the items inside it.

Comment: `string.punctuation` doesn't include so-called *smart quotes*.  You could use `punctuation = string.punctuation + '“' + '”'` to remove them as well.

Comment: And as others have pointed out, in `'“is',`, the character `“` is a "smart quote", not a normal ASCII quote.

Comment: I assume this is a homework question, but you could use `import re` and `re.findall(r'[a-zA-z]+',text)` to find all contiguous strings of letters in a text.

Comment: Hi Mark. thank you very much. I really didn't recognize those "smart quotes". I thought they were just the usual quotes. Thank you very much. I've been trying to get it to work for more than 5 hours. Thank you guys for your time and your patience. Have a great and productive day ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real texts may contains too many tricky symbols: n-dash `–`, m-dash `—`, over ten different quotes " ' ` ‘ ’ “ ” « » ‹› et cetera, et cetera...

It makes little sense to try to count all the possible punctuation symbols. Common way is try to get only letters (and spaces). Easiest way is to use RegExp:

```
import re

text = '''“Why, my dear, you must know, Mrs. Long says that Netherfield is
taken by a young man of large fortune from the north of England;
that he came down on Monday in a chaise and four to see the
place, and was so much delighted with it that he agreed with Mr.
Morris immediately; that he is to take possession before
Michaelmas, and some of his servants are to be in the house by
the end of next week.”

“What is his name?”

“Bingley.”

“Is he married or single?”

“Oh! single, my dear, to be sure! A single man of large fortune;
four or five thousand a year. What a fine thing for our girls!”

“How so? how can it affect them?”

“My dear Mr. Bennet,” replied his wife, “how can you be so
tiresome! You must know that I am thinking of his marrying one of
them.”

“Is that his design in settling here?”'''

# remove everything except letters, spaces, \n and, for example, dashes
text = re.sub("[^A-z \n\-]", "", text)

# split the text by spaces and \n
output = text.split()

print(output)
```

But actually the matter is much more complicated than it looks at first glance. Say `I'm` is a two words? Probably so. What about `someone's`? Or `rock'n'roll`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your text contains this character ” as double-quotes instead of ". ” doesn't exist in string.punctuation so you are not removing it. Maybe it is better to change your del_punctuation function a little:

```
def del_punctuation(item):
    '''
        This function deletes punctuation from a word.
    '''
    punctuation = string.punctuation
    for c in item:
        if c in punctuation:
            item = item.replace(c, '')
        
    item = item.replace('”','')
    item = item.replace('“','')
    return item
```

Comment: `”` are so-called closing quotation marks, but there is about the same number of opening quotation marks `“` (there is the subtle difference). So you will need to add one more replace line at the very least. And, well, that's only the beginning of real problems.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You're right! I edited my post to replace both opening and closing quotations, but I think your answer is more general and the better way is to keep only letters. @YuriKhristich